Protecting email domain/IP reputation when proxying user-generated content as a CRM
How do I, as an operator of a CRM who lets users send outbound mail on our behalf (using a subdomain of ours - like users.example.com), protect our domain/IPs reputation and avoid ending up flagged as spam by inbox providers?

My client operates a CRM-like platform that allows their customers (businesses that sell things) to respond to users' inquiries. Inquiries come from many different channels, but are ultimately translated to e-mails sent both to the agents (employees of the business customer) and the original user who inquired. The CRM effectively acts as a middleman and forwards the messages back and forth while capturing them so they are also visible in the web UI.
When an inquiry comes in, the flow is as follows:

CRM agent (which could be using a consumer-grade email like GMail or Outlook) gets a message from user-123@user.example.com with part of the original text
end-customer gets an email from an address like inquiry-123@user.example.com with the agent's (potentially canned) response
both sides of the conversation can login and pursue the conversation on the web (an account is created for them if they don't have one already - in that case they can use a password reset flow to gain access)
or they can just reply directly to that email, and it will be sent back and forth. A nontrivial number of users (on both sides) exclusively use e-mail and never use the web UI

We effectively operate as a middleman and aggregation platform. The e-mails we send are a mixed HTML/plain text one with a branded template (with our brand) that ultimately contains the user's/agent's reply as-is.
We already cover all the basics:

SPF, DKIM and DMARC are configured and check out as valid as per GMail's "view original" feature
VERP is applied by our sending provider, so the envelope email actually varies per-recipient, and they handle bounces and prevent us from sending any more e-mail to the address that bounced. Downside is that our From address domain is user.example.com but our envelope address is user-example-com-bounces@1234.someesp-example.com. Not sure if this matters much
we use a large bulk e-mail sending provider that has internal integrations with most inbox providers' spam reporting flows, so they also get those and prevent us from sending more spam to them. Our "spam" reporting metrics are very good on there, and any spam flag will prevent any further mail to that address from being sent
we use a dedicated sending IP, rented from the ESP and it's been exclusively ours for several years now
email volume is pretty constant, and our ESP takes care of obeying providers' rate-limits, so I doubt it's related to spikes in volume

Now the problem is that customers often report that their e-mails end up in the spam folder of their prospective customers. The basics like SPF/DKIM/etc are already covered, so I assume this must be linked to domain/IP reputation.
Additional details:

some marketing e-mail is sent via the second-level domain (so if our user-generated-content domain is user.example.com, marketing is sent via example.com)
while marketing e-mails have an unsubscribe link and List-Unsubscribe headers (implementing GMail's one-click unsubscribe flow), those user-generated messages do not

I can see potential risks here:

spam/scam can come in via the various inquiry channels. This then gets sent to the agent's (potentially consumer-grade) e-mail, gets caught by their inbox provider and tanks our domain/IP reputation
business customer's account gets compromised, spam/scam/phishing content is sent on their behalf by the bad guys. Same as above, our domain/IP reputation gets dinged
business customers' replies contain commercial keywords (this is a CRM after all), that while perfectly legitimate and solicited by the end-customer over a different channel, is invisible to the inbox provider, looking like bulk outbound sales spamming
those replies may be canned and sent automatically (generally, when an end-customer inquires, a canned message is sent to them automatically, and when the human agent finally comes around to it they may get an actual human response). Inbox providers may see a lot of very similar/identical emails and conclude we're sending out trash, despite again all of this being solicited by the customer (but via a different channel invisible to the provider). On the other hand, most marketing e-mail is completely identical by default, and that seems to be tolerated, so not sure if this theory holds much water
at least for Google, I am not sure if "bulk-email status" carries over across subdomains. Their docs say that once a "sender" is marked as bulk, that status is permanent - however they don't seem to elaborate on what "sender" means - does it means the second-level domain, the subdomain, or even the sending IP? It's probably a safe assumption to say that "we" are considered a bulk sender now purely based on volume, but not sure how exactly that maps to the various subdomains we use
we can't sign up to Microsoft's SNDS or JMRP program as that requires IP-level authentication (based on IP whois data) but our IP is still owned by our ESP. Not sure if this is a big deal though as our ESP presumably has integration with their spam email reporting flow and handles it on our behalf as described earlier

I'm looking for advice from others who may have operated a similar system on how to avoid this.
Potential ideas I have:

separate agent-targeted and end-user-targeted email domains. This means emails to agents (which contain raw inquiry text, is more likely to have spam and has much higher volume) is sent from one subdomain, while agent replies to end-customers (less volume, much less likelihood of spam) come out from another subdomain. Is there known evidence how inbox providers rank reputation of subdomains? Can we get away with subdomains or do we need to use separate second-level domains altogether? What about sending IP - can we reuse the same one or do we need a separate one too?
run all e-mails through SpamAssassin (or similar) and only send them out "for real" if they're above a certain threshold. Downside is that SpamAssassin (or similar) is very basic when it comes to spam detection nowadays, so I doubt it would do much (either it'll let too much spam through, or if we crank it up enough it's likely to have false positives)
obvious solution is to avoid inserting user-generated-content (which may contain spam) in the e-mails but this is a bit of a dealbreaker as a lot of agents and users rely on an email-first workflow. Forcing them to view the e-mail in the CRM UI would break said workflow so we'd like to avoid it as much as possible.
add unsubscribe links and List-Unsubscribe headers to those e-mails. The question is, what should the workflow be when pressed, if any, both for an agent and end-customer, given this is not actually a single "list"? For agent: do we just pause all inbound inquiries to that e-mail address until manually rectified in the UI? For end-customers: do we stop all future e-mail from the platform entirely? Do we stop only for the given agent? The former is likely going to lead to people accidentally clicking and subsequently missing responses to their inquiries from all our customers - for the latter, is it even going to do anything? Other agents' replies will still go through, and from an inbox provider's perspective both come from our domain, so they won't even be able to tell that an actual "unsubscribe" happened. Should we be naughty and add the link/header anyway to trick the inbox provider but lead to a FAQ page that merely explains why such emails can't be unsubscribed from?
let business customers bring their own domain. We'd give them DNS records to set on their domain (SPF, DKIM, etc) and we'd send on their behalf (or even SMTP credentials if they have their own outbound SMTP). That way, in theory, we would shard the domain-level reputation across many customers - reducing per-domain volume, and limiting the blast radius of any spam incident to that specific domain. The sending IP would still stay the same though - is there docs/evidence/consensus on how much IP reputation (as opposed to domain) plays a role?


Seems you've covered most of your basics. A few extra ideas: 1) Ensure you have reverse PTR records for all your sending IPs. 2) Note that reputation is IP and subdomain-based. 3) Newsletters are more typically marked as SPAM by customers, it's better to send them from a dedicated subdomain and IP. 4) Use several tools to scan your emails, domains, IPs and ensure everything is correct (don't rely only on Google's Show Original report). 5) Ensure headers are correctly formatted 6) Signup for Google Postmaster Tools or Microsoft SNDS. 7) Ensure DKIM/SPF/DMARC alignment
